# Listening to events in JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-loop

I have heard a lot about how JS is single threaded and asynchronous, and I know about the event loop, and the callback queue.

**What I don't understand is how can a single threaded language be listening to events and adding event handlers to the queue while it executes other code?**

For example clicking a button while a long loop is running will add its callback to the queue even though the thread is occupied.

Thank You

Comment: Because, for want of a better analogy, it's like a waiter delivering an order to table B, then stopping to take an order from table C and, on the way back to the kitchen, glancing over at table A to see if they need attending to. All these actions are performed serially, (ie. in a single thread) but by constantly checking and re-checking, the same single waiter is able to attend to tables A, B and C.

Comment: @Rounin So does the JS engine pause execution of the loop (In my example) at times to check if any events happened, queues their callbacks, and then resumes the loop?

Comment: It doesn't pause, no. _"The event loop continuously checks the **call stack** to see if there’s any function that needs to run."_ See: [The Javascript Event Loop by Flavio Copes](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the OS (or Javascript, for code-generated events) sends events to the JS in the browser, and these events are put on a queue for for processing. Javascript's one thread takes events off the queue and processes them until there are none left, at which time it waits for the next event to come in. For more, read about message queues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

Comment: Does that mean that the OS is aware of events happening inside the browser, like a button or any element in the DOM being clicked?

Comment: No. My understanding is that the OS simply sends very basic UI events - Mouse/Key up/down and mouse move with x,y coordinates for the mouse events. The application/browser interprets these events within its context.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, **browsers are not written in javascript**, and javascript is not what handles events.

UI events are first messaged to the browser by the OS, then the browser will handle these messages and queue a task to build up the DOM Event and dispatch it, where the related JavaScript callbacks may finally fire.

Only the last part involves JavaScript. You can very well have an User Agent (UA) that doesn't implement JavaScript but still does handle some UI events (e.g CSS pointer-events, HTML inputs, media controls etc.)

How this is handled will depend on the UA.

For very long, in the exact example you gave, browsers were unable to handle the clicks that were fired while the event loop was busy (IIRC latest IE still wasn't able to do so). It's only in modern browsers that they started to use [multi-process architectures](https://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture) which are able to communicate ([Inter-Process Communication](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication)) by sharing different message queues.

So even though the "main" renderer thread that does execute the various tasks of the event loop is busy, e.g executing js, other processes can still run in parallel and queue new tasks on the appropriate task queue.
When the renderer thread is done with its long task, a new task has been queued and it can process it.